# how to kill subprocess children when it is taking too much time in windows python?

Tags: python, subprocess

Right now I am using coupling my ipython notebook with xfoil using subprocess and psutil library to run some calculation.
However, in some case, xfoil cannot get convergence and it just keeps running. How can I time the communication and kill the process when the time runs out?

```
import psutil as ps
from subprocess import PIPE
import time
pro = ps.Popen(['xfoil.exe'],
                stdin=PIPE,
                stdout=None,
                stderr=None,
                encoding='utf8')
#execute the script
res = pro.communicate('\n'.join(scri))
```

here is the code that uses psutil to communicate with xfoil in python notebook.

Below is my script to run xfoil calculation.
Due to the fact that the calculation is all running in `pro.communicate()` function. I cannot use `time.sleep()` function as if xfoil not responding, it never gets to `time.sleep` function. How can I solve this problem?

```
['load backup/S813.txt',
 'S813',
 'MDES',
 'FILT',
 'EXEC',
 ' ',
 'PANE',
 'OPER',
 'ITER 150',
 'RE 300000',
 'VISC 300000',
 'PACC',
 'teste.txt',
 ' ',
 'ALFA 10.1',
 'PACC',
 ' ',
 ' ',
 ' ',
 'QUIT\n']
```

Comment: You could take a look at [pyexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) maybe it can help, it can start(`.spawn()`) external apps and inspect(`.expect()`) the output looking for patterns and or timeouts. So in case of a timeout you'll have the child process reference so you can kill it.

Comment: Thank you Lohmar, I will try to have a look